# Strange icons in title bar if a window is maximized

Tags: ubuntu, awesome-wm, title-bar

I'm using version included in Ubuntu 16.04 (3.5.6). If a window is set to maximized, as per following rule in `rc.lua`

```
{ rule = { class = "Firefox" },
  properties = { maximized = true } },
```

The titlebar displays these icons:

[image: displayed these icons.]

Do you know if I can get rid of them?

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of them by adding these lines to your `theme.lua`:

```
theme.tasklist_floating = ''
theme.tasklist_maximized_horizontal = ''
theme.tasklist_maximized_vertical = ''
```